# redirect to login via routing.yml if no user

Tags: symfony, authentication, redirect, routes

I need to redirect users to the login page if they're not logged in, and only for one page. And take them back to the page (which has a variable get parameter) after login.

Right now, I have it in my controller, but I'd like to take it out in the routing.yml (or anywhere else).

```
if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('client_login', ['_target_path' => $request->getRequestUri()]);
}
```

I've tried in security.yml

```
access_control:  
    - {path: ^/my_path.*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

but didn't find how to keep my get param in the URI.

Do you know if there's a way to do it?

Comment: should work with the firewall in security.yml check the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html

Comment: Well, when you connect usually you are redirected to the customer details, so the default_target_path is already used. In the end, I decided to put an extra flashbag while redirecting users, so I cannot use anything else but controller. Thanks anyway ;)